# How to get data from excel and pass excel values as parameters in SQL query on pentaho etl jobs

Tags: mysql, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-design-studio

I'm new to the pentaho etl jobs .. I need to get data from excel and pass the excel sheet value to MySQL query as parameter. If it's possible in etl pentaho jobs .. any know please  help me

Answer (score 0):

You create a transformation and use 'Microsoft Excel' as your input, make whatever transformation you need to do and add 'Table output' as you destination where you define your database connection. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

as per understanding of your problem your parameters are defined in excel file and you want to use it in sql step.

You create a transformation and use 'Microsoft Excel' as your input, use 'set variable' and then use them as part of sql query parameters dynamically